# Opening a user form in Powerpoint via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

I am trying to open a user form which I have created in a PPTM file via VBScript. Code for VB script is as below. This does seem to be working. It is simply opening that macro PPTM and closing it. Any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit

Dim pptApp, pptPresentation, CurrentDirectory

dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(CurrentDirectory + "\Revison Macro V1.pptm",True)

On Error Resume Next
pptApp.Run "Revision"
If Err Then

End If

pptPresentation.Close
pptApp.Quit

Set pptPresentation = Nothing
Set pptApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: I assume you meant to say that it is *not* working, correct?

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier: Yes It is not working correctly. It was supposed to show me the userform which I have created in PPTM file. But it is not doing that. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Then please edit your question, because currently it says something different.

Comment: @HarshitPandey Did my answer assist you?

Answer (score 1):

A Few code revisions

1. `Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(CurrentDirectory + "\Revison Macro V1.pptm",True)` >> VBScript uses "&" rather than "+" even though this worked fine, it's better to stick to the correct string handling.
2. The userform needs to be indirectly called to pause the vbscript. So create a separate `Sub` and call it "Call_Revision". The code will be simple and straightforward as follows:

   ```
   Sub Call_Revision
       Revision.Show
   End Sub
   ```
3. When you execute the `.Run` command, it needs to know how to find the code to run the UserForm. So now that we have established our sub, we can use that to show the form.

   From: `pptApp.Run "Revision"`

   To: `pptApp.Run "Revison Macro V1.pptm!Module1.Call_Revision"`
4. If you are waiting for the user to close out the userform to execute the rest of the code and exit the PPTM file, you can apply the following OnClose event within the Userform:

   ```
   Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
        Application.Quit
   End Sub
   ```

   And the Full Code:

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Dim currppt : currppt = "Revison Macro V1.pptm"
   Dim ModuleName: ModuleName = "Module1"
   Dim OpenUF : OpenUF = "Call_Revision"
   Dim pptApp, pptPresentation, CurrentDirectory
   dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
   Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
   Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(CurrentDirectory & "\" & currppt,True)
   On Error Resume Next
   pptApp.Run currppt & "!" & ModuleName & "." & OpenUF
   msgbox "Done"

   pptPresentation.Close
   pptApp.Quit

   Set pptPresentation = Nothing
   Set pptApp = Nothing
   ```